# Como plotar um gráfico de linha com cores diferentes dependendo do valor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Suponha os seguintes dados:

```
set.seed(1)
y<-rnorm(101)
x<-seq(from=0, to=100,by=1)
```

Quero fazer um plot com uma linha que tenha cor diferente para valores negativos.

Para fazer um gráfico de pontos basta o comando abaixo:

```
plot(x,y,col=ifelse(y>0,"blue","red"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, se altero para um gráfico de linha não funciona.

```
plot(x,y,col=ifelse(y>0,"blue","red"),type="l")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tento fazer com o `ggplot2` também não está dando certo. Ele atribui ao segmento da linha a cor do ponto anterior.

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
df$cat<-y>0
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=cat)) + geom_path(aes(group=1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer para o R atribuir corretamente a cor vermelha para valores negativos e cor azul para valores positivos no plot de linha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma "solução" parcial seria gerar um spline com muitos pontos (uns 100 por exemplo) que aí as cores teriam menor probabilidade de ficarem em lugar errado.  Mas essa solução pode gastar muita memória se sua base de dados for grande e vai suavizar o gráfico. Ex:

```
df2 <- data.frame(spline(df$x, df$y, n = 100*nrow(df)))
df2$cat <- df2$y>0
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y))+ geom_line(data=df2, aes(color=cat, group=1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]